# Using awk to bin values in a list of numbers

Tags: awk

I have a large data file consisting of many colums, and i would like to bin the (say) third column and output to a separate file.

By binning i mean the following:

I have a list of numbers say:

```
1
4
1
1
1
1
```

I want the average of sets of (say) three consecutive numbers.

My final output should be

```
2
1
```

The first entry is the average of

```
1
4
1
```

And the second entry is the average of the next three numbers,

```
1
1
1
```

How do i achieve this using awk?

Answer (score 10):

Use this awk command:

```
awk '{sum+=$1} NR%3==0 {print sum/3; sum=0}' inFile
```

Comment: +1. also `awk '{sum=$1; getline; sum+=$1; getline; sum+=$1; print sum/3}'`

Comment: Thanks so much @glennjackman using getline is also a nice way of calculating avg.

Comment: +1 for a good solution. Don't use getline for this. Imagine the impact if the OPs requirement changes to average 7 numbers instead of 3.