# Awk average of n data in each column

Tags: awk, average

"[Using awk to bin values in a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043503/using-awk-to-bin-values-in-a-list-of-numbers)" provide a solution to average each set of 3 points in a column using awk.

How is it possible to extend it to an indefinite number of columns mantaining the format? For example:

```
2457135.564106 13.249116 13.140903 0.003615 0.003440
2457135.564604 13.250833 13.139971 0.003619 0.003438
2457135.565067 13.247932 13.135975 0.003614 0.003432
2457135.565576 13.256441 13.146996 0.003628 0.003449
2457135.566039 13.266003 13.159108 0.003644 0.003469
2457135.566514 13.271724 13.163555 0.003654 0.003476
2457135.567011 13.276248 13.166179 0.003661 0.003480
2457135.567474 13.274198 13.165396 0.003658 0.003479
2457135.567983 13.267855 13.156620 0.003647 0.003465
2457135.568446 13.263761 13.152515 0.003640 0.003458
```

averaging values every 5 lines, should output something like

```
2457135.564916  13.253240   13.143976   0.003622    0.003444
2457135.567324  13.270918   13.161303   0.003652    0.003472
```

where the first result is the average of the first 1-5 lines, and the second result is the average of the 6-10 lines.

Comment: not very sure what you mean. Could you paste the desired output together with your attempts? anubhava's script in the other question looks quite nice and easy to play with

Comment: Use an array of sums and `for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)` loop to control the summing.  For printing, you have to determine what level of fidelity to the original format you are interested in, and how you're going to determine that format.  What happens if a value is moving between 99999.95 and 100000.05, for example?  Are you just using space-separated numbers with 6 decimal places?  If so, it is easy.  If you need to ensure 7, 2, 2, 1, 1 digits before the decimal point even if the numbers have only 5, 1, 1, 1, 1 digits before, then you have to work harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer to [Using `awk` to bin values in a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043503/using-awk-to-bin-values-in-a-list-of-numbers) is:

```
awk '{sum+=$1} NR%3==0 {print sum/3; sum=0}' inFile
```

The obvious extension to average all the columns is:

```
awk 'BEGIN { N = 3 }
     { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) sum[i] += $i }
     NR % N == 0 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                   {
                       printf("%.6f%s", sum[i]/N, (i == NF) ? "\n" : " ")
                       sum[i] = 0
                   }
                 }' inFile
```

The extra flexibility here is that if you want to group blocks of 5 rows, you simply change one occurrence of 3 into 5.  This ignores blocks of up to N-1 rows at the end of the file.  If you want to, you can add an END block that prints a suitable average if NR % N != 0.

For the sample input data, the output I got from the script above was:

```
2457135.564592 13.249294 13.138950 0.003616 0.003437
2457135.566043 13.264723 13.156553 0.003642 0.003465
2457135.567489 13.272767 13.162732 0.003655 0.003475
```

You can make the code much more complex if you want to analyze what the output formats should be.  I've simply used `%.6f` to ensure 6 decimal places.

If you want N to be a command-line parameter, you can use the `-v` option to relay the variable setting to `awk`:

```
awk -v N="${variable:-3}" \
    '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) sum[i] += $i }
     NR % N == 0 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
                   {
                       printf("%.6f%s", sum[i]/N, (i == NF) ? "\n" : " ")
                       sum[i] = 0
                   }
                 }' inFile
```

When invoked with `$variable` set to 5, the output generated from the sample data is:

```
2457135.565078 13.254065 13.144591 0.003624 0.003446
2457135.567486 13.270757 13.160853 0.003652 0.003472
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I modified your example with double quotes and escaping `\$` and `\"` symbols in order to embed your awk code in a bash script so that the `3` now is a bash parameter.

Comment: Use: `awk -v N=$bash_var '…code as before…'` — it is a better way to pass variables into `awk` scripts.  You'd drop the BEGIN block, of course.

Comment: @leonardvertighel - NO, absolutely do NOT put the script in double quotes and start escaping `$`s and `"`s, it is completely the wrong approach. Do what Jonathan suggests plus read http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24 and get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you very much for the link. I think @Jonathan added the `-v` part  after my comment.