# Calculate sequential average and median from file using awk

Tags: awk

This is my input file (there are thousands of rows):

```
$ cat file.txt
1 495.03
2 503.76
3 512.28
4 520.75
5 529.17
```

I'd like to use `awk` to calculate the median of the first column over X (let's say 1-100) number of rows and the average of the corresponding values of the second column. `awk` would then move the the next set of rows (101-201) and do the same, i.e. median of the first column and average of the second column and so on. Needless to say, I'm trying to learn `awk` and have tried several previous solutions but couldn't quite make it work.

From a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352241/awk-average-of-n-data-in-each-column), I found that I can calculate the average this way:

```
awk '{sum+=$1} NR%3==0 {print sum/3; sum=0}'
```

How does this work exactly (i.e. what does this `{sum+=$1}` expression mean?) and how can I adapt this for median? Btw, the first column will always be sorted.

Thanks in advance,
TP

Answer (score 2):

If the records are sorted, the median will be just the average of `50`th and `51`st values.

```
$ awk      '{r=NR%100; sum+=$2} 
      r==50 {m=$1} 
      r==51 {m=(m+$1)/2} 
      r==0  {print m, sum/100; sum=0}' file
```

this will work if number of records is a multiple of 100, otherwise you need to handle the last group which will have a different size.

There are other definitions for "median" for even number of records but that's something you should specify.

**Explanation** define `r` to be the remainder by mod 100, in essence the relative position in each block of 100 records.  For the median we take the average of 50th and 51st records, `sum` aggregates the second field value for each 100 block.  When the remainder is 0, we complete each block, print median and average (sum/100) values; reset `sum` for the next block.

Comment: Thanks, mind commenting your code?
Thank you, it works. Mind commenting your code so I can learn something?
`'{r=NR%100; sum+=$2} # define variable r as the sum of 100 lines?`
`r==50 {m=$1} # take the 50th value from the first column and store it as m variable?`
and the rest?

Answer (score 2):

***note:** This contains a bit more information wrt running means and medians for unsorted data. This should be seen as an addendum to the original question.*

If you want to compute the running average over the last *n* terms (assume *n = 100*) then you have to take care of how you handle the first *m* records with *m < n*. A way to handle this is to place the values in an array where the index is the modulo of *n*. This way you always have the last *n* terms in your array :

**running average of `$i`:**

```
awk '{a[NR%100] = $i; s=0; for(j in a) { s+=a[j] }; print "avg:" s/length(a) }'
```

You can, however, remove the `for`-loop by keeping track of `s`:

```
awk '{s+=$i; if (NR%100 in a) s-=a[NR%100]; a[NR%100]=$i; print "avg:" s/length(a) }'
```

**running median of `$i`:**

A way to compute the median can be done with `gawk` in which we assume that the array is sorted for array-traversal by value

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc" }
     { a[NR%100] = $i }
     { k=0; m=0;
       for(j in a) { k++
           if (k >= length(a)/2  ) m+=a[j]
           if (k <= length(a)/2+1) {m+=a[j]; break }
       }
       print "med:", m/2
     }'
```

or if you want it a bit lighter on the if-conditions

```
awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_asc" }
     { a[NR%100] = $i }
     { k=0; m=0;
       for(j in a) { k++
           if (k < length(a)/2  ) continue
           if (k > length(a)/2+1) break
           m+=a[j]
       }
       print "med:", (length(a)%2==0 ? m/2 : m)
     }'
```

If you don't want to use the pre-sorted concept, then the computation of the median becomes much more difficult. A possible way would be making use of [selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) as explained [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/find-median-of-unsorted-array-in-on-time).

Comment: Thanks but I'm still confused; when I run your average code on a file containing sequential values (1,2,3,4,5,6...100). I get avg:1, avg:1.5, avg:2... Not quite sure how that works and what do we actually compute here.

Comment: @ThePresident what is computed is the running average. I.e. the first line is the average of _{1}_, the second of _{1,2}_, the third of _{1,2,3}_ ... the 100th of _{1,...,100}_ and then the 101st of _{2,...,101}_, etc only the last 100 terms

Comment: Oh I see, makes sense now.

Comment: @ThePresident The reason I gave this answer is to create a bit more insight in running averages and medians and also because your title could be interpreted to fit this answer.