# Successive averaging of repeating data but different number of lines

Tags: awk, average

I have the following format of data:

```
         1        3
   1.723608      0.8490000
   1.743011      0.8390000
   1.835833      0.7830000
         2        5
   1.751377      0.8350000
   1.907603      0.7330000
   1.780053      0.8190000
   1.601427      0.9020000
   1.950540      0.6970000
         3        2
   1.993951      0.6610000
   1.796519      0.8090000
         4        4
   1.734961      0.8430000
   1.840741      0.7800000
   1.818444      0.7950000
   1.810717      0.7980000
         5        1
   2.037940      0.6150000
         6        7
   1.738221      0.8330000
   1.767678      0.8260000
   1.788517      0.8140000
   2.223586      0.4070000
   1.667492      0.8760000
   2.039232      0.6130000
   1.758823      0.8300000
...
```

Data consists of data blocks. Each data block has the same format as follows:

1. The very first line is the header line. The header line contains the ID number and the total number of lines of each data block. For example, the first data block's ID is 1, and the total number of lines is 3. For the third data block, ID is 3, and the total number of lines is 2. All data blocks have this header line.
2. Then, the "real data" follows. As I explained, the number of lines of "real data" is designated in the second integer of the header line.
3. Accordingly, the total number of lines for each data block will be number_of_lines+1. In this example, the total number of lines for data block 1 is 4, and data block 2 costs 6 lines...

This format repeats all the way up to 10000 number of data blocks in my current data, but I can provide this 10000 as a variable in the bash or awk script as an input value. I know the total number of data blocks.

Now, what I wish to do is, I want to get the average of data of each two columns and print it out with data block ID number and a total number of lines. The output text will have:

ID_number      number_of_lines    average_of_column_1     average_of_column_2

using 5 spaces between columns with 6 decimal places format. The result will have 10000 lines, and each line will have ID, number of lines, avg of column 1 of data, and avg of column 2 of data for each data block. The result of this example will look like

```
1     3     1.767484     0.823666
2     5     1.798200     0.797200
3     2     1.895235     0.735000
...
```

I know how to get the average of a simple data column in awk and bash. These are already answered in StackOverflow a lot of times. For example, I really favor using

```
awk '{ total += $2; count++ } END { print total/count }' data.txt
```

So, I wish to this using awk or bash. But I really have no clue how can I approach and even start to get this kind of average of multiple repeating data blocks, but with a different number of lines for each data block.

I was trying based on awk, following
[Awk average of n data in each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352241/awk-average-of-n-data-in-each-column)
and
https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/135829-partial-average-column-awk.html

But I'm not sure how can I use NR or FNR for the average of data with a varying number of total lines of data, for each data block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS='\t' '$2 ~ /\./ {s1 += $1; s2 += $2; next} {if (id) {print id, num, s1/num, s2/num; s1=s2=0} id=$1; num=$2} END {print id, num, s1/num, s2/num}' file

1  3  1.76748  0.823667
2  5  1.7982   0.7972
3  2  1.89524  0.735
4  4  1.80122  0.804
5  1  2.03794  0.615
6  7  1.85479  0.742714
```

If you have `gnu awk` then use `OFMT` for getting fixed size decimal numbers like this:

```sh
awk -v OFMT="%.6f" -v OFS='\t' '$2 ~ /\./ {s1 += $1; s2 += $2; next} {if (id) {print id, num, s1/num, s2/num; s1=s2=0} id=$1; num=$2} END {print id, num, s1/num, s2/num}' file
1   3   1.767484    0.823667
2   5   1.798200    0.797200
3   2   1.895235    0.735000
4   4   1.801216    0.804000
5   1   2.037940    0.615000
6   7   1.854793    0.742714
```

---

An expanded form:

```sh
awk OFMT='%.6f' -v OFS='\t' '
$2 ~ /\./ {
   s1 += $1
   s2 += $2
   next
}
{
   if (id) {
      print id, num, s1/num, s2/num
      s1 = s2 = 0
   }
   id = $1
   num = $2
}
END {
   print id, num, s1/num, s2/num
}' file
```

Comment: Thank you. May I ask some questions? 1) Is this method work with other delimiters like OFS=' ' or ','? 2) Can I ask what is $2 ~ /\./ this part doing? Is this 'read the N amount of line where N is the number in $2'? 3) If I want to use printf, which print should I need to modify to printf with formats? First or second? 4) How the looping works with if (id)? Sorry for so many questions

Comment: `$2 ~ /\./ ` checks presence of a dot in 2nd column. We can use `printf` and leave use of `OFMT` if you are not using gnu-awk. Can you check your awk version with `awk -V`

Answer (score 2):

And yet another one:

```sh
awk -v num_blocks=10000 '
BEGIN {
  OFS = "\t"
  OFMT = "%.6f"
}
num_lines == 0 {
  id = $1
  num_lines = $2
  sum1 = sum2 = 0
  next
}
lines_read < num_lines {
  sum1 += $1
  sum2 += $2
  lines_read++
}
lines_read >= num_lines {
  print id, num_lines, 
    sum1 / num_lines,
    sum2 / num_lines
  num_lines = lines_read = 0
  num_blocks--;
}
num_blocks <= 0 {
  exit
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
awk -v qnt=none 'qnt == "none" {id = $1; qnt = $2; s1 = s2 = line = 0;next}{s1 += $1; s2 += $2; ++line} line == qnt{printf "%d     %d     %.6f     %.6f\n", id, qnt, s1/qnt, s2/qnt; qnt="none"}'
```

The above is expanded as follows:

```
qnt == "none" 
{
  id = $1;
  qnt = $2;
  s1 = s2 = line = 0;
  next
}
{
  s1 += $1;
  s2 += $2;
  ++line
}
line == qnt
{
  printf "%d     %d     %.6f     %.6f\n", id, qnt, s1/qnt, s2/qnt; 
  qnt="none"
}
```

After a data block is processed (or at the beginning), record header info.
Otherwise, add to sum and print the result when we've done with all lines in this block.

Comment: May I ask what is the difference between two qnt=none at the beginning? You used qnt=none 'qnt == "none"  but how these non and "none" different from each other and what are they doing in this script? Thanks.

Comment: @exsonic01 `-v qnt=none` is to set `qnt` to `"none"` in the script so that awk can compare `qnt` to the string `"none"`. It can be initialized to anything that doesn't appear in the "size" field. Because we're not sure if `id` could be 0, `if(id)` may fail. Also, we can't be sure if there's always a decimal point in the data block, so I avoid comparing `$2` with `\.`.